# nodejs-mysql Enable formatting nested arrays for bulk updates

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express

I want to do bulk updates easily:

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JMqHd.png)

```
var arr = [];
for(var i = 0; i < studentIDs.length;i++){
    arr.push([parseInt(grades[i]),parseInt(studentIDs[i]),parseInt(courseID)]);
}
connection.query('update chooseCourse set grade=? where studentID in (select id from student where studentID = ?) and courseID = ?',[arr],function(err,result){
   console.log(results); 
   if(results.affectedRows){
       //do something
   }
})
```

but there're errors. the results is undefined and Cannot read property 'affectedRows' of undefined.

Comment: `results` is not defined in the callback `function(err,result)`

Comment: isn't the issue.  results is right in my project.